# Bootstrap 5 tooltip, popover and toasts not working in Ruby on Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, webpacker

I'm using a Railsbytes script to install bootstrap 5 alpha; https://railsbytes.com/public/templates/VB0s5v.

However, I can't get any of the tooltips and popovers to work. Not sure even where I should put the scripts or if I have to add anything to it in order to enable them. Would anyone please be so kind and provide some guidance. Thanks a lot!

/ Jacob

Example of js I suspect I need to add somewhere according to https://v5.getbootstrap.com:

```
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
```

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this too but have got them working now. This is my workflow for getting Bootstrap5 working with Rails6.

- `yarn add bootstrap@next`
- `yarn add @popperjs/core`
- create file `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` which is where I will add custom css
- add the following to the top of the new file:

```
# app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss

@import "bootstrap"
```

- In order for the application to import your custom css from the javascripts folder, add the following to your application layout file add `<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`. The pack_tag indicates that this will be handled by webpacker. The layout file will then look like:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

- finally to get everything working add the following to the bottom of app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
import "../stylesheets/application"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
  var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
  })

  var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
  var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
  })
});
```

Just as a test I then added the following Bootsrap components to my home page (or any page to test):

```
# index.html.erb

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks you! :)

Comment: @whatapalaver, Nice one!!!! Literally had to create a new rails app with nothing else to try and get my head around this popover and tooltip not working issue. 

This :)

import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

rather then just 

import "bootstrap"

helped me so much!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since version 5, Bootstrap bundle files already contain **Popper**, so there's NO need to add this package to your `package.json`

You should also be able to import only what you need, for example:

```js
import { Tooltip } from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle";

// Rest of your imports and/or other JS code...
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // or "turbolinks:load"
  const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll(
    '[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'
  );

  [...tooltipTriggerList].map((el) => new Tooltip(el));
});
```